# Neo4j 4.4.11 enterprise - Causal Cluster Deployment using Terraform

Tags: azure, kubernetes, neo4j, terraform

I followed the instructions from here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.4/kubernetes/quickstart-cluster/server-setup/ and deployed a cluster of three core members using Terraform.

Used helm-charts: https://github.com/neo4j/helm-charts/releases/tag/4.4.10

Used neo4j version:  Neo4j 4.4.11 enterprise

The code structure is as follows:

```
module/neo4j:
\-main.tf
\-variables.tf
\--core-1/main.tf
\--core-1/variables.tf
\--core-1/core-1.values.yaml
\--core-2/main.tf
\--core-2/variables.tf
\--core-2/core-2.values.yaml
\--core-3/main.tf
\--core-3/variables.tf
\--core-3/core-3.values.yaml
```

So the root main.tf creates modules of each core. Nothing special, nothing fancy.

The helm deployment is as follows:

```bash
resource "helm_release" "neo4j-core-1" {
  name      = "neo4j-core-1"
  chart     = "https://github.com/neo4j/helm-charts/releases/download/${var.chart_version}/neo4j-cluster-core-${var.chart_version}.tgz"
  namespace = var.namespace
  wait      = false

  values = [
    templatefile("${path.module}/core-1.values.yaml", {
      share_secret  = var.share_secret_name
      share_name    = var.share_name
      share_dir     = var.share_dir
      image_name    = var.image
      image_version = var.image_version
    })
  ]

  timeout      = 600
  force_update = true
  reset_values = true

  set {
    name  = "neo4j.name"
    value = "neo4j-cluster"
  }

  set_sensitive {
    name  = "neo4j.password"
    value = var.password
  }

  set {
    name  = "dbms.mode"
    value = "CORE"
  }

  # backup configuration
  set {
    name  = "dbms.backup.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "neo4j.resources.memory" # sets both requests and limit
    value = var.memory
  }

  set {
    name  = "neo4j.resources.cpu"  # sets both requests and limit
    value = var.cpu
  }

  set {
    name  = "dbms.memory.heap.initial_size"
    value = var.dbms_memory
  }

  set {
    name  = "dbms.memory.heap.max_size"
    value = var.dbms_memory
  }

  set {
    name  = "dbms.memory.pagecache.size"
    value = var.dbms_memory
  }

  set {
    name  = "causal_clustering.minimum_core_cluster_size_at_formation"
    value = 3
  }

  set {
    name  = "causal_clustering.minimum_core_cluster_size_at_runtime"
    value = 3
  }

  set {
    name  = "causal_clustering.discovery_type"
    value = "K8S"
  }

  dynamic "set" {
    for_each = local.nodes

    content {
      name  = "nodeSelector.${set.key}"
      value = set.value
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is: The deployment passes like only 1 out of 10 times. Whenever the deployment fails, it is due to a time-out of the Terraform helm_release of one or two core members stating: "Secret "neo4j-cluster-auth" exists.

Looking into the log of the one (or two) members already deployed, the startup failed, because the cluster is missing members. (initialDelaySeconds have been configured for each core member and have been increased testwise too)

[kubernetes pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2NLO.png)

```
2022-11-17 08:59:22.738+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on 0.0.0.0:7474.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting Neo4j database server at /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:227) ~[neo4j-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:180) ~[neo4j-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at com.neo4j.causalclustering.core.CoreGraphDatabase.createManagementService(CoreGraphDatabase.java:38) ~[neo4j-causal-clustering-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at com.neo4j.causalclustering.core.CoreGraphDatabase.<init>(CoreGraphDatabase.java:30) ~[neo4j-causal-clustering-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseManagementServiceFactory.createManagementService(EnterpriseManagementServiceFactory.java:34) ~[neo4j-enterprise-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseBootstrapper.createNeo(EnterpriseBootstrapper.java:20) ~[neo4j-enterprise-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:142) [neo4j-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:95) [neo4j-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:24) [neo4j-enterprise-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'com.neo4j.dbms.ClusteredDbmsReconcilerModule@5c2ae7d7' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Failed to join or bootstrap a raft group with id RaftGroupId{00000000} and members RaftMembersSnapshot{raftGroupId=Not yet published, raftMembersSnapshot={ServerId{c72f54d8}=Published as : RaftMemberId{c72f54d8}}} in time. Please restart the cluster. Clue: not enough cores found".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:463) ~[neo4j-common-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110) ~[neo4j-common-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:218) ~[neo4j-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    ... 8 more
```

I tried different settings for the following two config parameters:

- causal_clustering.discovery_type
- causal_clustering.initial_discovery_members

First the combination of using default discovery_type=K8S which omits any set initial_discovery_members.

Second the combination of discovery_type=LIST and defining initial_discovery_members by name and port 5000.

Both settings let to an successful clustering in like 1/10 times.

As the cluster members are searching for each other while getting deployed, another thing being tried is configuring terraform conditions that two of the cluster members get build with "wait=false" and the third member gets a depends on:

`module "neo4j-cluster-core-3" {  depends_on = [module.neo4j-cluster-core-1, module.neo4j-cluster-core-2]`

Comment: Can you share your terraform code how you deploy the helm charts

Comment: sure, i'll update the main post